# Createjs import files from indesign and place them on canvas

Tags: javascript, css, import, createjs, adobe-indesign

So i have this project where i need to manipulate pictures, text and other objects to create: birthday, wedding and other cards.

Each of these cards contain fonts, styles ect. Now the tool i have found that i will edit these pictures with is   [Createjs](http://createjs.com/)

An example of the pictures that i want to import is:

[image]

As you can see from this picture there is alot of elements and alot of text. all text are editable but has to stay the same font.

So i need to important each object as a spire and import the fonts and colors.

Does anyone know if there is any easy way to do this or am i stuck creating my own tedious way?

Comment: Did you tried GM (graphicsmagick) node module. I solved the same problem with GM. here is my question. but see my own answer  how I solved this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490009/how-to-pass-image-buffer-data-to-gm-in-graphicsmagic

Comment: i would recommend you to try to use `fabricjs` from:http://fabricjs.com/ it has also create methods to create such canvas editors

Comment: Marc, have you found an answer to this? I'm looking for a way to import indesign files into fabric.js canvas..

Comment: @AvaelKross Sadly nothing more than the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want edit elements and text, you will using fabric.js(fabricjs.com)
Using this, You will do easy edit elements and text.